# Printing TableView in JavaFX displays junk/other language characters

Tags: java, javafx, printing, javafx-tableview

I'm trying to print a TableView in JavaFX application. When I pass the TableView directly to the PrinterJob.printPage(TableView) the text data is in some other language but the view shows up fine i.e in English on the screen.

```
...
final TableView addItemTableView = (TableView) tabAnchorpane.getChildren().get(1);

Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE, Printer.MarginType.DEFAULT);
double scaleX = pageLayout.getPrintableWidth() / addItemTableView.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();
Scale scale = new Scale(scaleX, scaleX);
addItemTableView.getTransforms().add(scale);
PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
if (printerJob.showPrintDialog(stage.getOwner()) && printerJob.printPage(pageLayout, addItemTableView)) {
    printerJob.endJob();
}
...
```

The TableView is populated with data from the Task class

```
public class Task implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    private transient StringProperty description;
    private transient IntegerProperty priority;
    private transient ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dueDate;
    private transient StringProperty status;
    private transient ObjectProperty<LocalDate> startDate;
    private transient ObjectProperty<LocalDate> endDate;
...
}
```

[Actual Print Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1waaM.jpg)

[Expected Print Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M53ub.jpg)

Comment: Just guessing here! Check your computer language settings?

Comment: Its set to English itself

Comment: Maybe if you have a ResourceBundle or whatver? Check that effectively the locale used is the one you are expecting (US) not sanskrit or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with JDK 7. When I switched to JDK 10 the issue is resolved. The print preview pages show up in English as expected.